# how to convert right single quotation to single quote in java

Tags: java, text, unicode

I'm accepting input from user while copy pasting text from Microsoft Word single quote is coming as right single quote.

that is

```
Original Text:  speaker’s
Expected Text : speaker's
```

is there any way or libraries to convert characters similar to these

Comment: I don't think there is a library. You want to convert unicode to a subset and adjust characters that are missing in the subset. You can use the replace-methods of string.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("[‘’‚‛‹›′‵]", "\'").replaceAll("[“”„‟″‴‶‷»«]", "\"";` (use UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
"speaker’s".replaceAll("’", "'")
```

Comment: Or simply `replace('’', '\'')`.